# find zero blocks greater than 32KB in files

Tags: python, file, io

what is the fastest way to check if are blocks of zeros in a lot of files. The blocks should be greater than 32000 bytes of zeros.
The following code is to slow:

```
empty_blocks = []
min_length = 32000
block = False
begin = -1
data = open(file_name,'rb').read()
for i,byte in enumerate(data):
        byte = ord(byte)
        if byte == 0x00 and block == False:
            block = True
            begin = i
        elif byte != 0x00 and block == True:
            block = False
            if length >= min_length:
                empty_blocks.append((begin, i - begin))
            begin = -1
```

Comment: Do the blocks have to have any alignment requirement met also? What about overlaps if the alignment requirement isn't 32k?

Comment: The files where corrupted by the bittorrent sync protocol. I got the information that the smallest piece size that the bittorrent protocol transfers is 32kb. I'm not sure if the zero blocks are n * 32kb with n=1,2,3,4 or any value greater than 32768.

Answer (score 3):

So, assuming the block size of 32768 bytes, I came up with something along the lines:

```
from functools import partial

BLOCKSIZE = 32 * 1024

with open('testfile.bin', 'rb') as f:
    for block_number, data in enumerate(iter(partial(f.read, BLOCKSIZE), b'')):
        if not any(data):
            print('Block #{0} is empty!'.format(block_number))
```

<s>The `sum()` is the fastest way to determine if every byte in a sequence has a value of zero. I don't think it's possible to make it faster than `O(n)`.</s>
[VPfB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5378816/vpfb) suggested using `any()`, which is very very fast, as it terminates on the first non-zero element, instead of going through the whole sequence.

Output example:

```
Block #0 is empty!
Block #100 is empty!
Block #200 is empty!
```

It processes about <s>~100 MB/sec</s> 2 GB/s on my machine, which is fast enough I hope.

Comment: I think the test should be terminated when first non-zero byte is found. `block_is_empty = not any(data)`

Comment: Yes! How couldn't I see something that obvious?  
It's now about 20 times faster, thank you!

Comment: I tried you code but it won't work. The any(...) returns True for a empty block. The data variable holds a str with chr(0) values

Comment: str? We read the file as bytes.
It worked for me, I created a random file and zeroed every 100th block.
You can see the output in my answer.

Comment: did you use Python 2.x or 3.x?I use 2.7.x. I set a breakpoint at the if-clause. When data is a empty block I got type(data)=str and any(data)=True.

Comment: ok I found the problem. In python 2.x type(data)=str in python3 type(data)=byte. The code above only works with python3

Answer (score 0):

Start by mmapping the file:

```
import mmap, os, re
f = open(filename)
m = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), os.fstat(f.fileno()).st_size, prot=mmap.PROT_READ)
```

Using regular expressions is convenient:

```
for match in re.findall(b'\0{32768}, m):
    print(match.start())
```

but strings are even faster:

```
z32k = '\0' * 32768
start = 0
while True:
    start = m.find(z32k, start)
    if start < 0:
        break
    print(start)
```

only 32k-aligned blocks:

```
for match in re.finditer('.{32768}', m, re.DOTALL):
    if max(match.group()) == '\0':
        print(match.start())
```